Can't see any change after updateing Vue component inside Laravel Nova project
I am having issue I wasn't able to fix with googleing or stackoverflowing and its super strange one. It could easily be lack of knowledge on my side so have mercy.
I have made an application recently using Laravel Nova (hosted with Homestead/Vagrant), everything worked perfectly locally + online. When I say everything I mean everything (Laravel, Nova, Vue...)
Couple days ago, I cloned project to new PC (standard procedure). I thought everything works until I started editing NOVA-COMPONENTS. Once edited components are built with "npm run dev".. I see no changes in browser... I believe I have tested everything related to browser (clear cache, new browser, system restart...). Tried clearing laravel cache also without effect.
Please let me know.. if you need bit more info just let me know.
Steps I did when started working with specific components:
1. npm install inside nova-component folder
2. added console.log('test') to Card.vue
3. npm run dev inside nova-component folder
4. component is mixed and i see console.log('test') in app.js
5. no changes when that specific component is visited with browser (there is no console log output)

I have tried npm run watch, watch-poll etc without luck. All of them build component but I still see old version in browser.
I see that app.js file is being built again when i change some Card.vue and it contains my changes but browser is still using old javascript files.
